# how inline element <a> contain block level elements here?

Tags: html

```
<a href="#">
      <h1>Our Plus Plan</h1>
      <h2>The most popular choice of our customers</h2>
      <p>
        Benefit from increased storage and faster support to ensure that
        your mission-critical data and applications are always available!
      </p>
    </a>
```

We know that, inline elements can't contain block element. But here is working fine. How is that possible here?

Answer (score 0):

Well because I think html is not sensetive if there is a newline so whatever you put inside the  tag, will turn into a link

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The content model of the `<a>` element [is defined as *transparent*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), which means it can be either "flow content" or "phrasing content" depending on it's parent or ancestor. Those content models replaced the traditional separation between inline elements and block elements.

Regardless, browsers would not break the pagr even of you put something invalid like a `<div>` inside a `</span>`.